# Jquery selector for nested class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div class="child">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is not predictable what markup is separating the `div`'s with classes.

I want a jquery selector that gets the first nested `child` element after a `parent` element but not any more deeply nested `child` elements.  In the example, I want the first `child` div but not the second.

I can't use `.parent > .child` because of the intervening `div`.

I can't use `.parent > div > .child` because that intervening `div` is not predictable.

I can't use `.parent .child` because that would pick up the second `child`.

Is there a way to select for a non-immediate child of some given class without picking up more deeply nested ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd echo [Josh's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29290470/82548), to filter out unwanted `.child` elements, but using the `.not()` method:

```
$('.parent .child').not('.child .child')
```

```js
$('.parent .child').not('.child .child').css('border-color', 'red');
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 5vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}

div[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div class="child">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or the `:not()` selector:

```
$('.parent .child:not(".child .child")')
```

```js
$('.parent .child:not(".child .child")').css('border-color', 'red');
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 5vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}

div[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div class="child">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, with `filter()`:

```
$('.parent .child').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents('.child').length === 0;
});
```

```js
$('.parent .child').filter(function() {
  // retains only those .child elements who
  // have no parents matching the '.child' selector:
  return $(this).parents('.child').length === 0;
}).css('border-color', 'red');
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 5vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
div[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child">
      <div>
        <div class="child">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: I selected this as the right answer because it included all the suggested options.  I would have up-voted all 4 answers to date if I'd had enough reputation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `$('.parent .child').first()` or `$('.parent .child:first')` which is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter through the `.child` elements and then determine if the `.child` element has a parent with class `.child` using the [`.parentsUntil()` method](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/).

In doing so, you can conditionally return the element only if it is at the top level.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kg6hz0xx/)

```
var $element = $('.parent .child').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).parentsUntil('.parent', '.child').length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following selector works for me:

```
$('.parent .child:not(.child .child)')
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mnnt51an/)